# Jenkins - How to set workspace root after v2.110 W10

Tags: jenkins, workspace

Manage Jenkins | Configure System  -  the Advanced option has been removed in v2.110 
Additionally, Advanced Project Options has also been removed from the job configuration settings.

Removal update found here - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52054

What is an alternative method of changing work space root in v2.121+ on Win10 (I'd prefer not downgrading as I'd likely run into compatibility issues).

Answer (score 1):

With the `JENKINS_HOME` system property you can specify the root directory, e.g.:

```
-DJENKINS_HOME=/var/opt/jenkins/...
```

or

```
-DJENKINS_HOME=C:/Jenkins/...
```

As noted in [JENKINS-50164](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50164), since Jenkins ~ 2.110 you have to use two additional system properties if you want to customize the locations of the builds and workspaces directories: `jenkins.model.Jenkins.buildsDir` and `jenkins.model.Jenkins.workspacesDir`. Their current default values (Jenkins 2.119) are:

- jenkins.model.Jenkins.buildsDir: `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds`
- jenkins.model.Jenkins.workspacesDir: `${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}`

See the Jenkins Wiki page [Features controlled by system properties](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties) for more details on those properties and for the placeholders supported when overriding the defaults.

Comment: Note that the answer to the Original Question concerns the workspace root which is in this answer but not at the top. The variable jenkins.model.Jenkins.workspacesDir controlls where the workspaces for the builds are created on the Jenkins master.